# How can I dynamically build a mongoose query that has an objectId?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to dynamically build a mongoose query. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to do this when the query contains an objectId.

I'm using mongoose 5.4.6.

My mongoose schema looks something like this:

```
stuff: String,
user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
moreStuff: String,
});
```

I need to dynamically build my query, and one of the possible fields to query for is `user`. The fields to query for are sent to the server via a `params` object. When the field I'm querying for is `stuff`, then it's easy. I just do something like the following:

```
let query = {};
query.stuff = params.stuff;

this.model('MyModel').find(query)...
```

However, I can't figure out how to search for user, because `params.user` is just the string version of the mongo id, but it needs to be formatted as `objectId("params.user")` for the query to work. That is, I need something like:

```
query.user = objectId("params.stuff");
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const MyModel = require('../models/mymodel')

let query = MyModel.findOne()

query.where('_id').equals(new ObjectId(params.stuff))
```